# How to make sure my css files is loaded after react component's css file

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack

I have a React.js app configured with webpack with serverside rendering. When user enters "lang" param in url I am loading one css file based on language. I want to make sure my language-specific css file loads at the end.

Right now my react component's css imports are overriding my global language css file.
How do I make sure the css rules written in language.css file overrides all css rules even those which load with dynamic components?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might already know this, but the reason this is happening is because your `language.css` file loads on page load which is followed by the render of your React components. So, the CSS styles closer to the component will take precedence over the globally applied CSS.

So now you essentially want to make your global styles in `language.css` override your inline React styles. For that you can simply add the `!important` flag with the styles in your css file. Like so:

```css
h1 {
  color: green !important;
}
```

Here's a working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-mw089k?file=/index.js

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do this, as there are hundreds of css rules in the language.css file.